# Animation of form resize from left to right

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using the following code to resize the form from right to left

```
while (this.Width >= 15)
{
  this.Width--;
  Application.DoEvents();
}
```

How would I get the same functionality when shrinking the form from left to right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
while (this.Width >= 15)
{
  this.Width--;
  this.Left++;
  Application.DoEvents();
}
```

Comment: thanks nice and simple, just what I was looking for!